# Unable to set Meld as a diff tool in Git Bash

Tags: windows, bash, git, user-interface, meld

Can someone help me to figure out how can I make Meld work on Git Bash for Windows 10? I have followed some instructions but neither worked for me.

After I typed these commands, nothing happened:

```
git config --global diff.tool meld
git config --global difftool.meld.path "/c/Program Files(x86)/Meld/Meld.exe"
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

After using `git difftool` command, I get this weird error:

```
git config option diff.tool set to unknown tool: merge
Resetting to default...

This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.
See 'git difftool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git difftool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld kompare gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare emerge vimdiff
2 files to edit.
```

I also tried;

- /c/Progra~2/meld/bin/
- "/c/Program files (x86)/Meld/"
- "c:/Program files (x86)/Meld/"

My config file:

```
[user]
    name = user
    email = email@sample.com

[merge]
    tool = meld

[mergetool "meld"]
    cmd = meld --auto-merge \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\" --output \"$MERGED\" --label \"MERGE (REMOTE BASE MY)\"
    trustExitCode = false

[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    keepBackup = false

[diff]
    guitool = meld

    tool = meld
[difftool "meld"]
    cmd = meld \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" --label \"DIFF (ORIGINAL MY)\"
    path = C:/Program Files(x86)/Meld/Meld.exe
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is not well written, and there is a missing space character.

And you should define `cmd` instead of `path`.

Eventually, this should work for you:

```
git config --global diff.tool meld
git config --global difftool.meld.cmd "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/Meld.exe\" \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""
git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

**Edit:**

If you want Git guidelines of valid tools, you can check it with:

```
git difftool --tool-help
```

Anyway, after our exchanges, you decided to use P4merge; This is a consequent update of my answer.

This is the way to setup it:

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.cmd "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Perforce/p4merge.exe\" \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""
git config --global diff.tool p4merge
git config --global difftool.p4merge.cmd "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Perforce/p4merge.exe\" \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""
```

Comment: Added the missing space character in my .config file, and I tried this commands but it keeps showing the same error.

Comment: Can you post your current complete config file please?

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://pastebin.com/8rG4bkLy although I'm new in Bash, I did many research but still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Ok... You must 1/ remove the path definition of difftool meld. 2/ fix the path of meld executable for mergetool (define the full path like for difftool) 3/ maybe use `git diff` instead of directly difftool.

Comment: Does it fix your issue?

Comment: I tried all these options, unfortunately neither of them worked. After I tried using P4merge somehow it worked like a charm. I heard that there is a problem about Meld windows distribution.

Comment: Ok, I consequently updated my answer to get it complete; and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also with Git Bash on Windows 10 and this config works fine with Meld :

```
diff.guitool=meld
merge.tool=meld
difftool.meld.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe
mergetool.meld.path=C:/Program Files (x86)/Meld/meld/meld.exe
```